# How to list git commits for Android release?

Tags: android, git, gitweb

Does anybody know how to determine whether a certain git commit, for example [this one](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=commitdiff;h=6d56b530e189d7213ec77d43d3d8af97fee04179) from [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8676), was rolled into a particular Android release such as [2.2 Froyo](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-22-and-developers-goodies.html)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a web-only solution, or do you have a clone of the repo so you can actually use git to get what you need? And what exactly do you want, besides whether that single commit is in the release - all commits between the last release and this one? That sounds like it might be an awful lot of commits.

Comment: Just the one commit is sufficient, not an awful long list of commits =)

Comment: @Brad Hein: And the part about web-only versus running git commands in your own clone?

Comment: Web only. I am not building it

Comment: All right, so it's a gitweb question, not a git question. I don't know a way within gitweb, unfortunately - though it's quite easy if you have a clone, which is why I asked. I also edited your links - you'd linked to an issue, not a commit, but there was a commit mentioned in the last comment on the issue. And by the way, if you use the @ to tag someone whose comment you're responding to, it'll notify them so you don't have to wait for them to happen to look at your question again (if they ever do).

Comment: @Jefromi The issue I linked to is the issue that I need to know whether or not made it into Froyo.

Comment: I verified, as described in my answer, that the *commit which fixes the issue* made it into Froyo. I don't really know what you mean by the issue making it in. The issue presumably *existed* in every version up until that commit, and none of the ones after it.

Comment: My understanding was that code changes had to go through a review process before being accepted into a release. I didn't want to assume that the "fix" was automatically accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My one suggestion is to just look at the [shortlog of the appropriate branch](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/froyo-release) (that's froyo-release; I'm guessing froyo is a maintenance branch) and see if the commit's in the shortlog. The commit in question is way, way back - on the 143rd page of the shortlog. I found it just by skipping back until the dates were right. Not very fancy.

I'm guessing this is all you can do with gitweb, though it is under pretty active development, so perhaps someday it'll get that "Branches: " feature from gitk. @Jakub Narebski is fairly active on SO; he might be able to provide a more definitive answer. (not sure if @-notification works in answers or just comments)

Comment: Wow thank you for your help with this! I learned a few tricks with gitweb. Confirmed that the fix is in Froyo as commit comment `2009-08-25 Jaikumar Ganesh Add local frames for parsing properties and processing...` on page 143: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/froyo-release;pg=143